# CoreData generates an optional attribute when it's supposed to be non-optional

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, option-type

I noticed that when I create a String attribute as non-optional on the xcdatamodel file, when Xcode automatically generates the NSManageObject definition, it creates it as optional. I set a default value as well. Same thing for the relationships. It doesn't do it when I create Bool or Int16 attributes. Very confusing... Do you know why it does that, or what I do wrong?

[image]